# Magento 1.6.2 cant not reindex product flat data

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Our magento 1.6.2 cant not reindex product flat data. It also sometimes shows 'There was a problem with reindexing process.'

I tried many solutions from the experience of other users. No result. We imported bulk products but we are not sure it's the cause of reindexing problem.

What could be the ideal solutions?

This is the command i used in shell:

```
php /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsphp5 /home/user/domains/my domain../public_html/shell/indexer.php
```

This is the error from exception.log

```
2012-08-09T14:55:43+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`galagearbox/#sql-1662_1fc419`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_4_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCA)
Trace: #0 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#6 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(327): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#7 /home/corecolu/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2548): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#8 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(816): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->addForeignKey('FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')
#9 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1390): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(4)
#10 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#11 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(336): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#12 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(207): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#13 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(253): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(124): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#16 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#17 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /home/corecolu/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /home/corecolu/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reindexing errors in Magento can have many reasons, so I'm afraid there never will be an "ideal" solution covering all possible errors.

Since you've posted a non-technical error message, I guess you've tried to reindex the product flat data using the admin backend and saw the error message there.

I'd recommend to try to reindex again, but using the `shell/indexer.php` this time:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /abs/path/to/shell/indexer.php -- --reindex catalog_product_flat
```

This way you'll get more meaningful technical error messages, if reindexing fails.

Here's a list that shows which parameter to use for which index:

```
catalog_product_attribute     Product Attributes
catalog_product_price         Product Prices
catalog_url                   Catalog URL Rewrites
catalog_product_flat          Product Flat Data
catalog_category_flat         Category Flat Data
catalog_category_product      Category Products
catalogsearch_fulltext        Catalog Search Index
cataloginventory_stock        Stock Status
tag_summary                   Tag Aggregation Data
```

#### UPDATE

The exception you've added to your post tells, that the referential integrity between

```
catalog_product_flat_4.entity_id
```

and

```
catalog_product_entity.entity_id
```

was found being corrupted.

Usually this means some record(s) contain(s) `null` in the field `catalog_product_entity.entity_id`, where they are expected to contain existing `entity_id`s.

Before trying to fix this, please **backup your database first**.

Now, to find the corrupted record(s), query your database with:

```
SELECT
    a.entity_id
FROM
    catalog_product_flat_4 AS a
LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity AS b ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id
WHERE
    ISNULL(b.entity_id)
```

The `entity_id`s found by this query are `entity_id`s in the table `catalog_product_flat_4`, which are corrupted and need to be deleted.

Delete the appropriate records in `catalog_product_flat_4`, and then try to reindex again.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting the following error for shell/inderer.php 


Warning: Unexpected character in input:  ' in /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsphp-5.3.10 on line 654

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsphp-5.3.10 on line 654
 [~]# Warning: Unexpected character in input:  ' in /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsphp-5.3.10 on line 654
>

Comment: please ignore indexer.php spelling mistake

Comment: This `lsphp-5.3.10` is **not** a standard Magento file. Please post the code around line 654 of the file `lsphp-5.3.10`, preferably into your question (unreadable in comment).

Comment: Thanks I'm hopeful and I'll try. Just curious to know the table that contains the main products information. From which table catalog_product_flat tables get back their information after reindexing?

Comment: They get the data back from the multiple EAV tables defined for the product entity, mainly `catalog_product_entity_*`.

Comment: i'm again facing the problem but i'm able to fix it by sql. do you think that's a magento bug? would it be good idea to execute the delete all ids by running the query in all flat tables with my own reindexing code separately? i can also think about it running through cron at mid night.

Comment: i've fixed this one too. this time, the problem was on flat table 1. i deleted the unmatched rows from the table and it worked. these kinds of issues happen usually when the mysql connection goes away or server partially completes the requests.

Answer (score 1):

```
create one file like reindex.php in your magento root directory with following code

<?php

    enter code here

// when you get status "Processing" instead of "Ready" in your index management run this script and it's working fine
// change the index order as per your requirement currently it's 7 for Catalog Search Index  you can set as per your requirement

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask( 0 );
Mage :: app( "default" );
Mage::log("Started Rebuilding Search Index At: " . date("d/m/y h:i:s"));
$sql = "truncate catalogsearch_fulltext;";
$mysqli = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$mysqli->query($sql);
$process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(7);
$process->reindexAll();
Mage::log("Finished Rebuilding Search Index At: " . date("d/m/y h:i:s"));

now save it and run it using browser and it will solved your problem

I hope you will get your solution. I will help you if you still getting problem.
```

Answer (score 0):

magento programatically re index
ID      Code

1       catalog_product_attribute

2       catalog_product_price

3       catalog_url

4       catalog_product_flat

5       catalog_category_flat

6       catalog_category_product

7       catalogsearch_stock

8       cataloginventory_stock

9       tag_summary

for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {

$process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);

$process->reindexAll();

}