# Magento URL Rewrite Indexer Error 500

Tags: magento

When running the indexing for url rewrite catalog, I'm getting an error 500 interal server error, but I cannot get it to generate any errors to the exceptions.log .. I've tried to empty the core_url_rewrites but with no luck, still getting error 500 and no log file. It's Magento 1.6.2

The error generated when the 500 screen turns up:
www.domain.com/index.php/admin/process/reindexProcess/process/3/key/caac7ef08590009411a43aa71a990192/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11928782/693207

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you running out of memory, allocate more in your .htaccess file:

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

512M should do it, if not try incrementing this value even more.

Comment: I've now changed it from 256 til 512 with no luck. Even the cron job which is running our indexing 2 times a day, cannot index it. The worst part is that I cannot get it to generate any errors, and it startet out of nothing

Comment: try 1024 if you have enough RAM. How many products / categories have you got?

Comment: 50000 products, and a couple of hundred categories

Comment: I needed more ram with 30K products and 3K categories; My index didn't run until I increased it to 1536M;

Comment: Tried to up it to 2048 still no luck. 
But as I added to my first post, I'm getting this error when the 500 screen appears: www.domain.com/index.php/admin/process/reindexProcess/process/3/key/caac7ef08590009411a43aa71a990192/

Comment: have you checked generic Apache error log? is php error reporting enabled?

Comment: Try reindexing from terminal as well:  php indexer.php --reindex all

Comment: This would have worked if it was allowed by the host. We have changed to another server, so it's working now. 

The error the Host got from the server: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whatabout timeouts? They too can lead to 500 errors.

Try putting something like this in .htaccess or php.ini:

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 86400
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
```