# Magento 1.7.0.2 Reindexing Product Attributes Error

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

Upon reindexing the Product Attributes in Magento 1.7.0.2, we are getting the following errors:

```
Product Attributes index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`xxdbnamexx`.`mage_catalog_product_index_eav`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `mage_catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id)' in /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#5 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#6 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ma...')
#7 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(48): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'mage_catalog_pr...', Array, false)
#8 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->insertData(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source), Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'mage_catalog_pr...', Array, false)
#9 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(113): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromTable('mage_catalog_pr...', 'mage_catalog_pr...', false)
#10 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Abstract.php(54): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
#11 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav.php(185): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Abstract->reindexAll()
#12 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav->reindexAll()
#13 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#14 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#15 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#16 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}
```

could anyone provide any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that what you are trying to do violates the foreign key constraint between `mage_catalog_product_index_eav` and `mage_catalog_product_entity`.

What this means is that you have entity_ids in the `mage_catalog_product_index_eav` table that do not occur in the `mage_catalog_product_entity` table. This could be because some entity_ids in `mage_catalog_product_entity` are null.

It could also be because the records that `mage_catalog_product_index_eav` tries to refer to are not there at all. In that case, you could remove the referring records from `mage_catalog_product_index_eav`.

In any case, you will have to figure out exactly what the offending records are. Check out the first answer on [Magento 1.6.2 cant not reindex product flat data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926651/magento-1-6-2-cant-not-reindex-product-flat-data) for pointers on how to do that. (It's not the exact same problem since they are dealing with flat data but still useful, I think.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. Tried running the following query and returned no results: `SELECT
    a.entity_id
FROM
    mage_catalog_product_index_eav AS a
LEFT JOIN
    mage_catalog_product_entity AS b ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id
WHERE
    ISNULL(b.entity_id)`

Comment: After a better look at your error, I realize it's caused by _inserting_ entity_ids into `mage_catalog_product_index_eav`. So, it seems the indexer is trying to create records in the index table for products that are not there.

Take a look at what user olivenet did here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/265847/#t376030 The gist of it is that you temporarily remove the foreign key constraint from `mage_catalog_product_index_eav`. (Don't forget to put it back when you're done!) Then run the indexer again. Now, you should be able to find the "problem products".